# Computer goes on deep sleep whereas being accessed through LAN

Tags: suspend, samba

I setup a samba share between my Ubuntu 20.04 and my Nvidia shield. I just noticed tonight that my computer goes on deep sleep even if I'm currently watching a video  from my Shield. Is it normal ? I guess it shouldn't go on deep sleep while the computer's hard drive is in use though ?

Cheers,

Xzi

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have this set up as a laptop computer rather than as a server. If you want to disable the automatic sleep, then go into the power screen of the configuration and settings. [image: Power Settings]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I'm aware of that setting and I was using for power saving though when I was running windows, while I was accessing my windows machine via Samba through my LAN, that was preventing my Windows Desktop going on deep sleep. I thought I would get the same behavior using Ubuntu.